# How to prevent textview below imageview from getting cut off inside relativelayout? - Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have an imageview then below it is a textview.  These are contained inside a relativelayout.  Why is the textview getting cut off?

my_fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"        
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_unique_img"
            android:id="@+id/uniqueImg"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="my multiple line text\ntest"
            android:id="@+id/txtTest"            
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/uniqueImg"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

parent_container.. The fragment is being added by code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/myFooter"
    android:layout_below="@id/myHeader"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you remove `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` from the ImageView that is messing up the TextView below and give a padding/margin instead (if you want). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
Think this will do. 

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_unique_img"
            android:id="@+id/uniqueImg"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="my multiple line text\ntest"
            android:id="@+id/txtTest"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/uniqueImg"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```